# WPF DataGridTextColumn direct edit

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagridtemplatecolumn

i have very simple `DataGridTextColumn` which should be modified on doubleclick event.
question is what should be added to avoid exception `System.InvalidOperationException: ''EditItem' is not allowed for this view.'`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding}" GridLinesVisibility="None" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding VariantSet, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="60" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

simple class:

```
Public Class CName
    Public Property Name As String = "not editable name"
End Class
```

on load simply added to datagrid

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Me.DG.Items.Add(New CName)
End Sub
```

when declared through template as following, there is no difference, same error

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

even when `Implements ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` is added to the CName, no difference

Comment: It's the view of whatever collection you're binding is likely the problem. Bind itemssource to a public property which is an observablecollection. You don't need mode twoway because when you edit you get a textbox. The text property of a textbox is marked to bind twoway as default.

Comment: even when i bind to list declared as 'Public NameList As ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of CName)' there is no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not shown us enough to tell what you're doing wrong.

Here's a working window with datagrid.

The code is c# but you can run it through a converter to vb if you particularly want vb.  I think it's a bad idea for a beginner to choose vb nowadays. Almost nobody publishes samples using vb.

In my mainwindow:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="SurName"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

That viewmodel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return people; }
        set { people = value; }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Chesney", LastName = "Brown" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Gary", LastName = "Windass" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Liz", LastName = "McDonald" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Carla", LastName = "Connor" });
    }
}
```

Person just has those two properties first and last name:

```
public class Person : BaseViewModel
{
    private string firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private string lastName;

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

That inherits from BaseViewmodel which just implements inotifypropertychanged.

```
public  class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here I am editing a row

[image]

Comment: you had right, poorly implemented INotifyPropertyChanged was an issue